# Recursive call in php over a json

Tags: php, recursion

I have this json data

```
$innerdata = json_decode('{
            "sync_block": false,
            "contacts": [{
                "con_title": "",
                "con_fName": "",
                "con_lName": "",
                "con_job_title": "",
                "emails": [{
                    "email": "",
                    "type": "",
                    "primary": false,
                    "nest_uid": "1_1_1536657342_lyBhkbkDfG",
                    "checked": false
                },
                {
                    "email": "",
                    "type": "",
                    "primary": false,
                    "nest_uid": "1_1_1536657342_lyBhkbkDfGLp",
                    "checked": false
                }],
                "phones": [{
                    "phone": "",
                    "type": "",
                    "primary": false,
                    "nest_uid": "1_1_1536657342_CQPBBUBRZN",
                    "checked": false
                }],
                "nest_uid": "1_1_1536657342_fpTI2RF3XK",
                "checked": false
            }]
        }');
```

Then I get the nest_uid that I need to find

```
$uid='1_1_1536657342_lyBhkbkDfGLp';
```

I need to do recursive call over the json and return the object whose

```
nest_uid == $uid
```

In the above json the output should be

```
{
                    "email": "",
                    "type": "",
                    "primary": false,
                    "nest_uid": "1_1_1536657342_lyBhkbkDfGLp",
                    "checked": false
                }
```

I tried writing a function but it doesn't work as expected

```
function  traverse($innerdata,$uid){
        $res=$innerdata;
        foreach($innerdata as $key=>$property)
        {
            if($key=='nest_uid'&& $property ==$uid)
            {
                break;

            }
            else if(is_array($property))
            {
                 foreach($property as $innerproperty){
                     echo "1";
                   traverse($innerproperty,$uid);     
                 }

            }
        }

       return $res;  

  }
```

if someone could help me would be great

Comment: is the structure unknown? Or will you always have a nest_uid in the "contacts" object and within the "emails" and "phones" objects? I ask this because if the structure is predictable, you don't need recursion. You only need recursion if the structure is unknown and you need to discover what all the properties of the object are every time.

Comment: @ADyson yes nest_uid exist in all the level, but number of levels deep is unknown for example , there could be another array in email in which ill have to get one of the component

Comment: ok thanks. And also please clarify, what goes wrong with your code currently? You say it doesn't work correctly but didn't say what it _does_ do - that would give us a head start.

Comment: @ADyson So my code currently is returning complete json object thats being passed rather the one which is matched

Comment: I think it's because you simply return $res each time You don't take any account of what is returned by the inner call to `traverse()`. So it forgets what happened within those calls. I can investigate it a bit further if you're still stuck.

Comment: @ADyson yes I realized that, umm what do you suggest I should do

Comment: well firstly you need to change `foreach($property as $innerproperty){
                     echo "1";
                   traverse($innerproperty,$uid);     
                 }` to `foreach($property as $innerproperty){
                     echo "1";
                  $res = traverse($innerproperty,$uid);     
                 }`...but I think this will still have a problem because if $res is correct after the first foreach, for example, you need to break here as well. So I think you need to repeat the loop over the keys here as well.

Comment: If that still doesn't help you, give me a little more time to test it out properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181156/discussion-between-vikram-and-adyson).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The searcher:

```
class Searcher
{
    private $data;
    private $uid;
    private $result;

    public function __construct($data, $uid)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->uid = $uid;
    }

    private function search($data, $path)
    {
        foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
            if (is_array($v) || is_object($v)) {
                $subPath = $path;
                $subPath[] = $k;
                if ((is_array($v) && isset($v['nest_uid']) && $v['nest_uid'] === $this->uid)
                    || (is_object($v) && isset($v->nest_uid) && $v->nest_uid === $this->uid)) {
                    $this->result[join('/', $subPath)] = $v;
                }
                $this->search($v, $subPath);
            }
        }
    }

    public function getResult()
    {
        if ($this->result === null) {
            $this->result = [];
            $this->search($this->data, []);
        }
        return $this->result;
    }
}
```

Demo code:

```
$innerdata = json_decode('{
            "sync_block": false,
            "contacts": [{
                "con_title": "",
                "con_fName": "",
                "con_lName": "",
                "con_job_title": "",
                "emails": [{
                    "email": "",
                    "type": "",
                    "primary": false,
                    "nest_uid": "1_1_1536657342_lyBhkbkDfG",
                    "checked": false
                },
                {
                    "email": "",
                    "type": "",
                    "primary": false,
                    "nest_uid": "1_1_1536657342_lyBhkbkDfGLp",
                    "checked": false
                }],
                "phones": [{
                    "phone": "",
                    "type": "",
                    "primary": false,
                    "nest_uid": "1_1_1536657342_CQPBBUBRZN",
                    "checked": false
                },
                {
                    "phone": "",
                    "type": "",
                    "primary": false,
                    "nest_uid": "1_1_1536657342_CQPBBUBRZN",
                    "checked": false
                }],
                "nest_uid": "1_1_1536657342_fpTI2RF3XK",
                "checked": false
            }]
        }');

$searcher = new Searcher($innerdata, '1_1_1536657342_lyBhkbkDfG');
var_dump($searcher->getResult());

//with multi items
$searcher = new Searcher($innerdata, '1_1_1536657342_CQPBBUBRZN');
var_dump($searcher->getResult());
```

Output:

```
test_tmp.php:81:
array(1) {
  'contacts/0/emails/0' =>
  class stdClass#3 (5) {
    public $email =>
    string(0) ""
    public $type =>
    string(0) ""
    public $primary =>
    bool(false)
    public $nest_uid =>
    string(25) "1_1_1536657342_lyBhkbkDfG"
    public $checked =>
    bool(false)
  }
}


test_tmp.php:85:
array(2) {
  'contacts/0/phones/0' =>
  class stdClass#5 (5) {
    public $phone =>
    string(0) ""
    public $type =>
    string(0) ""
    public $primary =>
    bool(false)
    public $nest_uid =>
    string(25) "1_1_1536657342_CQPBBUBRZN"
    public $checked =>
    bool(false)
  }
  'contacts/0/phones/1' =>
  class stdClass#6 (5) {
    public $phone =>
    string(0) ""
    public $type =>
    string(0) ""
    public $primary =>
    bool(false)
    public $nest_uid =>
    string(25) "1_1_1536657342_CQPBBUBRZN"
    public $checked =>
    bool(false)
  }
}
```

PS: Another approach if you want to process the first level (eg: `nest_uid` exists in the first level, just replace the `search` function in the `Searcher` class above):

```
private function search($data, $path)
{
    foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
        if ($k === 'nest_uid' && $v === $this->uid) {
            $this->result[join('/', $path)] = $data;
        }
        if (is_array($v) || is_object($v)) {
            $subPath = $path;
            $subPath[] = $k;
            $this->search($v, $subPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just testing your new function once

Comment: what if the "nest_uid" also exist in the first level like just before contacts?

Comment: I have updated my answer before and provided a new function. see the bottom @Vikram

Comment: yes i tried doing this https://gist.github.com/vikramIde/8bb860066ae219b6f6b98ed54c27681e

Comment: sorry my bad the json iwas providing had an error yes your answer works fine

Answer (score 0):

Just store current value before going through another array:

```
$jsonParentOfChild = function($array, $uid) use (&$parent, &$jsonParentOfChild) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            // Storing current value before going deep
            $parent = $value;
            $currentChild = $jsonParentOfChild($parent, $uid);
            if ($currentChild !== null) {
                return $currentChild;
            }
        } else {
            // This is where it should end
            if ($key == 'nest_uid' && $value == $uid) {
                return $parent;
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
};

$jsonArray = [json_decode($jsonObject, true)];
$parent = key($jsonArray);

var_dump($jsonParentOfChild($jsonArray, '1_1_1536657342_lyBhkbkDfG'));
var_dump($jsonParentOfChild($jsonArray, '1_1_1536657342_CQPBBUBRZN'));
```

See [live demo here](https://3v4l.org/5db5F)